# How to get U-Boot debugging symbols

Tags: linux, debugging, u-boot

I'm working on porting U-Boot to a custom board we're developing, based on the Texas Instruments AM5728, and I'm having some issues debugging U-Boot.  I can load and debug U-Boot SPL via JTAG, but I cannot step/reach hardware breakpoints once U-Boot proper is loaded via JTAG after the SPL finishes.  This is largely due to not knowing where the debugging symbol table exists in the U-Boot binary.  I've enabled the DEBUG macro in U-Boot and have had no success, so I'm figuring that if I can get the debug symbols, I can actually step to whatever errors I'm having.

Is there a way to get the debugging symbols from the build process/Makefile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few things to bear in mind here.  First, **spl/u-boot-spl** and **u-boot** are the ELF files for U-Boot and in the case of AM5728 you're going to be loading **MLO** and **u-boot.img** into memory to boot them.  The second thing to keep in mind is that fairly early on U-Boot relocate itself in memory from where it was loaded and into an address that it calculates and resumes running from.  The easiest way to obtain this value is, assuming your system boots to a prompt:

```
=> bdinfo
...
relocaddr   = 0xFFF6D000
reloc off   = 0x7F76D000
```

These values are system dependent but tell you both the absolute address in system memory and the offset to add to the linked in address to know where a given function resides now.  The **u-boot.map** file will list among other things where all functions are linked at.  How to tell your debugger where things are depends on the debugger in question.  For example, with gdb you would re-load the symbol-file and give it the new relocaddr value.

Comment: The problem that I have been having has been that I do not boot to a console, is there anything in the `u-boot.map` file that I can use to find that relocaddr or reloc off?

Comment: You can start debugging prior to relocation and will have 'gd' available to examine, and can see what gd->relocaddr is when it's being set.

Comment: this may be a bit out of scope with the original question, but I've found that my debugger does not allow me to place a breakpoint at any line that references gd->relocaddr, making it quite difficult to debug to it.  Simultaneously, I have no debug symbols for board_init_f.  Is there a way to enable these?  I also have found that defining DEBUG does not result in any printed debug messages.

Comment: To the first problem, you may need to learn to use gdb directly to solve your problem.  To the second problem, U-Boot always builds with debug symbols, and they are removed from certain outputs, but 'u-boot' will be a valid ELF application with all symbols.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 'removed from certain outputs'?

Comment: What I mean is that, for example, 'u-boot.bin' is 'u-boot' with things not required for runtime removed, so it will not have symbols.  u-boot.img is that in turn with another header on top.